# How to copy a div and its content, and append it somewhere else but keep original hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div element like:

```
<div id="abc">....</div>
```

It is hidden or `display:none` by default on page load.

I know want to append this div and its content somewhere else, and make it visible, but the original should remain not visible (or I can remove it).

How can I do this?

I'm currently appending it but it is showing up in 2 places.

Comment: What are you currently doing that it shows up in 2 places? Show us your code!

Answer (score 1):

Take the HTML from your hidden div and append it to your target using `.html()` and `.append()`

```
var html = $('div.hidden-div').html();
$('div.target-div').append(html);
```

To show the target div then remove the old one, do the following:

```
$('div.target-div').show();
$('div.hidden-div').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Deep clone, append, remove `id` attribute and show.

```
​​$("div#abc")
  .clone()
  .appendTo("div#other")
  .removeAttr("id")
  .show();​​​​​​
```

Remove or modify your `id` attribute, having multiple elements with same `id` is troublesome. If you happen to use CSS classes you could also use it this way:

```
.template {
  display: none;
}
```

```
​​$("div.template")
  .clone()
  .appendTo("div#other")
  .removeClass("template");​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is OK to remove it (as you said), just append it to the other element. The element will automatically be removed from the first place and never show up there.

```
$("#abc").appendTo(place2).show();
```